# Чем proxy через BeanPostProcessor отличается от AOP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Не могу понять, чем прокси класс который создается, когда я в BeanPostProcessor добавляю какую-нибудь логику после инит метода отличается от того прокси который создается когда добавляю логику через Spring AOP. Я так понимаю что и там и там используется либо Dynamic Proxy либо CGlib?

Answer (score 1):

Концептуально BeanPostProcessor - это дополнительная обработка при **создании** объекта -т.е. он вызывается для одного объекта 1 раз (ну по факту 2 раза - до и после инит метода), а АОП - это дополнительная логика уже в **работающем** объекте - и вызывается она столько раз сколько нужно. Отсюда все различия. Внутри proxy может не сильно отличаться.  Но обернуть большое количество методов/объектов намного легче через аоп - кода будет в разы меньше. Но зато когда надо полностью изменить объект - то лучше использовать первый вариант с BeanPostProcessor - так как оборачивать ничего не надо - и легче с нуля создать класс